# How to show/open dropdown list from upwards in Kendo Multiselect component for angular

Tags: html, angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have used kendo Multiselect dropdown list on my page. When I click on it, it is opening the list from top to bottom(downwards). For my requirement, I need to show it from bottom to top(upwards).

I have checked with kendo UI angular documentation for multiselect component. There are no options are available for this change.

Please help me with this requirement thanks in advance.

```html
<kendo-multiselect kendoMultiSelectSummaryTag [data]="data" (valueChange)="onChange($event)" [filterable]="true"
  [(ngModel)]="subValues" [textField]="textField" [valueField]="valueField" [clearButton]="false" [autoClose]="false"
  [value]="selectedValue" [popupSettings]="{popupClass: 'popupStyle'}" (keypress)="disableText($event)"
  (open)="onOpen($event)" (close)="onClose($event)">

  <ng-template kendoMultiSelectItemTemplate let-dataItem>
    <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" [disabled]="selectedValue.length===1 && isItemSelected(dataItem.text)"
      [checked]="isItemSelected(dataItem.text)">
    <label class="k-checkbox-label">{{ dataItem.text }}</label>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template kendoMultiSelectGroupTagTemplate let-dataItems>
    <span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s"></span>
    {{ dataItems.length }} selected
  </ng-template>
</kendo-multiselect>
```

[image]Screenshot is attached

Comment: The control will automatically open upwards if it's on the bottom half of the screen. There is no "default behavior" on how to control the expanded state of the multi select.

Comment: Actually two buttons are present behind that dropdown. that is reason need to show it upwards

Answer (score 1):

Example: [pop up position](https://dojo.telerik.com/uKOYosOb)

```
$("#optional").kendoMultiSelect({
    autoClose: false,
    popup: {
        origin: "top left",
        position: "bottom left"
    },
    animation: {
        open: {
            effects: "slideIn:up"
        }
    }
}).data("kendoMultiSelect");
```

Explanation taken from: [Telerik forum](https://www.telerik.com/forums/open-popup-up-(not-down))

> ...however, you should add some space above the widget. Otherwise, the
>   screen boundary detection will not allow the desired behavior.

Comment: This is jquery Kendo UI . I used Kendo UI for angular.